# unable to compare integer object in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am unable to compare "c" and "c1", even if value of object "c" prints 1
my code is as follow:-

```
         <%
          Integer c1=new Integer(1);
          Integer c =(Integer) session.getValue("login"); // value of login is int type in servlet
          out.println(c);  //it works correctly
          if(c==c1 && c!=null)   //it does not work correctly 
          {
           response.sendRedirect("homepage.jsp");
          }
          %>
```

please answer this question

Comment: if (c == c1), shouldn't it mean that already c is equal to c1, and therefore it is not null ???? I think you should check if (c != null), then, check if c is equal to c1

Comment: here you don't have to check for (c!=null) only check for (c==c1) because c1 has value 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(c!=null) {
    if(c==c1) {
        response.sendRedirect("homepage.jsp");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to explain why your code works and the OP's doesn't?

Comment: @hichris123  first, you have to check if c is not null... if c was null, you cannot even compare it to c1... it's somehow obvious...